# Getting the unique rows from a cell array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique, cell

I have a Nx4 cell array in Matlab which looks something like this:

```
id1 word11 word12 word13
....
id2 word21 word22 word32
....   
idN wordN1 wordN2 wordN3
```

where each of the four columns holds a string and the second column `(word11... wordN1)` can have duplicate values. I want to get another cell array but with unique rows according to the second column. so in the previous example if `word21` was the same as wordN1, the resulting array should have the following two rows only (doesn't matter which row of the duplicates gets chosen):

```
id1 word11 word12 word13    
....    
idN wordN1 wordN2 wordN3
```

I tried `unique(cellArray{2})` but it only returns the second column with the unique values and I want the whole row. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, given that this is your first question, I just thought I'd let you know that if you feel I have answered the question, then you should click the tick-mark next to my answer. If you are not satisfied with my answer, then let me know and I'll attempt to improve it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following should do it:

```
Z = {'a', 'b'; 'a', 'c'; 'a', 'c'; 'a', 'd'; 'a', 'b'};
[~, I1] = unique(Z(:, 2));
I1 = sort(I1);
Soln = Z(I1, :);
```

An explanation? I use the optional additional arguments of `unique` to obtain the indices of unique elements in the second column. I then `sort` this index so that we can preserve the original ordering of `Z`. Finally, I retrieve the rows of `Z` indexed by `I1`.

Note, it is a bit unintuitive that the `sort` actually preserves the original ordering rather than sorting it :-) The reason is that `I1` contains the row indices of the unique elements. Thus sorting it returns the row indices in order from smallest to largest, thus preserving the original order in `Z`.

Comment: +1 Note that the second tilde in the `unique` call is unneccessary: `[~,I1] = unique(Z(:,2));` will suffice

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Huh, interesting, you are correct. I was going off the official matlab documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), where the function syntax indicates it has either 1 or 3 outputs. Anyway, I've edited my answer, thanks Rody.